# How to unmarshal XML with multiple namespaces in different xml or ignore namespace in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have two XML's and corresponding Java files (created by trang.jar and xjc tools)

XML 1 :

```
<HSI_ContractDetailModificationRQ xmlns="http://axis.frontend.hsi.hotelbeds.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages/HSI_ContractDetailModificationRQ.xsd">
<Language>CAS</Language>
<Credentials>
    <User>PRUEBASHSI</User>
    <Password>HSI</Password>
</Credentials>
<Contract>
    <Name>TEST HSI</Name>
    <IncomingOffice code="51"/>
    <Sequence>29769</Sequence>
</Contract>
<MinimumStayList>
    <MinimumStay>
        <DateFrom date="20070401"/>
        <DateTo date="20070630"/>
        <MinNumberOfDays>4</MinNumberOfDays>
        <MaxNumberOfDays>12</MaxNumberOfDays>
    </MinimumStay>
</MinimumStayList>
</HSI_ContractDetailModificationRQ>
```

java file created by xjc :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"contract",
"roomList",
"minimumStayList"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "HSI_ContractDetailModificationRQ")
public class HSIContractDetailModificationRQ
extends CoreRequest
implements Serializable
{

private final static long serialVersionUID = 20070801L;
@XmlElement(name = "Contract", required = true)
protected Contract contract;
@XmlElement(name = "RoomList")
protected ServiceHotelRoomListRQ roomList;
@XmlElement(name = "MinimumStayList")
protected HSIContractDetailModificationRQ.MinimumStayList minimumStayList;

/**
 * Gets the value of the contract property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Contract }
 *     
 */
public Contract getContract() {
    return contract;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the contract property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link Contract }
 *     
 */
public void setContract(Contract value) {
    this.contract = value;
}

public boolean isSetContract() {
    return (this.contract!= null);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the roomList property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link ServiceHotelRoomListRQ }
 *     
 */
public ServiceHotelRoomListRQ getRoomList() {
    return roomList;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the roomList property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link ServiceHotelRoomListRQ }
 *     
 */
public void setRoomList(ServiceHotelRoomListRQ value) {
    this.roomList = value;
}

public boolean isSetRoomList() {
    return (this.roomList!= null);
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the minimumStayList property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link HSIContractDetailModificationRQ.MinimumStayList }
 *     
 */
public HSIContractDetailModificationRQ.MinimumStayList getMinimumStayList() {
    return minimumStayList;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the minimumStayList property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link HSIContractDetailModificationRQ.MinimumStayList }
 *     
 */
public void setMinimumStayList(HSIContractDetailModificationRQ.MinimumStayList value) {
    this.minimumStayList = value;
}

public boolean isSetMinimumStayList() {
    return (this.minimumStayList!= null);
}


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="MinimumStay" type="{}MinimumStayModRQ2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "minimumStay"
})
public static class MinimumStayList
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 20070801L;
    @XmlElement(name = "MinimumStay", required = true)
    protected List<MinimumStayModRQ2> minimumStay;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the minimumStay property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the minimumStay property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getMinimumStay().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link MinimumStayModRQ2 }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<MinimumStayModRQ2> getMinimumStay() {
        if (minimumStay == null) {
            minimumStay = new ArrayList<MinimumStayModRQ2>();
        }
        return this.minimumStay;
    }

    public boolean isSetMinimumStay() {
        return ((this.minimumStay!= null)&&(!this.minimumStay.isEmpty()));
    }

    public void unsetMinimumStay() {
        this.minimumStay = null;
    }

}

}
```

XML 2 :

```
    <HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRS xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06   /messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages         
/HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRS.xsd" echoToken="echotoken">
<AuditData>
<ProcessTime>438</ProcessTime>
<Timestamp>2007-02-12 16:42:37.242</Timestamp>
<RequestHost>10.0.1.221</RequestHost>
<ServerName>ITINTERNET26</ServerName>
<ServerId>LO</ServerId>
<SchemaRelease>2005/06</SchemaRelease>
<HydraCoreRelease>2.0.200702091006</HydraCoreRelease>
<HydraEnumerationsRelease>1.0.200702091006</HydraEnumerationsRelease>
<MerlinRelease>N/A</MerlinRelease>
</AuditData>
<Status>Y</Status>
</HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRS>
```

java file created by xjc :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"status"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRS")
public class HSIContractInventoryModificationRS
extends CoreResponse
implements Serializable
{

private final static long serialVersionUID = 20070801L;
@XmlElement(name = "Status", required = true)
protected YesNo status;

/**
 * Gets the value of the status property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link YesNo }
 *     
 */
public YesNo getStatus() {
    return status;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the status property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link YesNo }
 *     
 */
public void setStatus(YesNo value) {
    this.status = value;
}

public boolean isSetStatus() {
    return (this.status!= null);
}

}
```

If i unmarsh this
for XML 1

```
 HSIContractDetailModificationRQ hsi =  (HSIContractDetailModificationRQ) jaxbUnMarshallerForChannel.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(xmlString)));
```

i get Exception :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://axis.frontend.hsi.hotelbeds.com", local:"HSI_ContractDetailModificationRQ"). Expected elements are <{}HSI_ContractDetailModificationRQ>,<{}HSI_ContractDetailModificationRS>,<{}HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRQ>,<{}HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRS>
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:238)
```

If i unmarsh this
for XML 2

```
 HSIContractInventoryModificationRS  hsi = (HSIContractInventoryModificationRS)   jaxbContextForChannel.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(xmlInventoryRs)));
```

i get Exception :

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages", local:"HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRS"). Expected elements are <{}HSI_ContractDetailModificationRQ>,<{}HSI_ContractDetailModificationRS>,<{}HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRQ>,<{}HSI_ContractInventoryModificationRS>
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
```

I have seen in some site , it suggests to use package-info.java:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://axis.frontend.hsi.hotelbeds.com",    
elementFormDefault  =    
XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
  package com.cultagent4.hotelbeds.sa;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

I have used this , and xml 1 unmarshler works fine, but xml2 marshing fails .
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling with JAXB & XJC to build bindings to handle namespaces. I spent a lot of time on forums and googling. It does not works which makes me mad.

Atlast i have found a solution in a blog to ignore the namespace.
[here is the solution link](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/JAXB-Fails-to-handle-namespaces-td1062517.html)

Provided JAXB does not take into account namesapace of xml elements, it wrote the following code in order to ignore namespace while parsing.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.jmex.model.collada.collada_schema_1_4");
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            SAXParserFactory parserFactory;
            parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XMLReader reader = parserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
            Source er = new SAXSource(reader, new InputSource(sourceStream));
            HSIContractInventoryModificationRS hsi = (HSIContractInventoryModificationRS) u.unmarshal(er);
```

It works, JAXB unmarshalling is successful. (I hope this piece of code can help someone...)

Comment: can you also update your HSIContractInventoryModificationRS class ?